# How to change foreground color of selected item, which has custom foreground?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TreeView`, which contains custom-styled items, for instance:

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItems}">
    <TreeView.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmw:ManagedObjectViewModel}">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NameText}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ClassNameText}">
                        <TextBlock.Inlines>
                            <Run Text=" (" />
                            <Run Text="{Binding ClassName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            <Run Text=")" />
                        </TextBlock.Inlines>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ClassNameText}" Text="{Binding ClassName}" Visibility="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource InverseEmptyStringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Basically, items are displayed as two textboxes, one black and one gray. The problem is that when item gets selected, then both textboxes retain their foreground colors.

This happens because `Foreground` set from style overrides the value derived from visual tree (TreeViewItem).

How can I make these textboxes change color to white when selected?

The only solution that currently comes to my mind is kind of convoluted:

- Introduce a style to TreeViewItem to bind selection to viewmodel
- Use the selection to pick color for textboxes using e.g. a converter

This requires changes in viewmodels, what I'd like to avoid. Is there a better way using pure XAML?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem and below you have the solution.

I used the Tag property to set the default foreground state of each Textblock in Style, otherwise it could be used more generic to all Textblocks that inherit it.
Then I used a trigger when it is selected, then as foreground value it takes the color from the parent.

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayItems}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}} , Path=IsSelected}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}} , Path=Foreground}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vwm:ManagedObjectViewModel}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
                           Tag="Black"
                           Text="{Binding Path=ClassName}" />
                <TextBlock Tag="DarkGray"
                           Style="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

If you want really to change foreground in white just set
`<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}} , Path=Foreground}" />` to `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />`